# How do you call a website in which HTML is produced by server-side programs?

Tags: web

In many web applications, the server-side programs (e.g. NodeJS) only provide a Restful API for a front-end application (e.g. ReactJS) to consume.
So my question is, what are the terms used to distinguish a website which has separated front-end and back-end (like a website with ReactJS front-end and NodeJS back-end) from a website which has both front-end and back-end in one project (like a website written using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf)?

Comment: this would be better suited to english.stackexchange.com